# How to connect a hybrid application made in intel xdk with a mysql database? Any good resources?

Tags: intel-xdk

I've been searching for examples to connect my intel xdk application with mysql database but I can't find anything. I've read this information http://qnimate.com/create-a-intel-xdk-app-with-php-and-mysql-backend/ but they don't explain anything about the files and where information come from.
If anyone have good resources it would be a great help for me. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this how I did it

```
    // php script. Make sure this file is in your www folder if you are using wamp 

    <?php
        $data = array(); // array to store data
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','wtf'); // connection to database
    if(!$con){
        die('Error Occured ' . mysql_error());
    } // checking if connection was successfully 

    $sel_db = mysql_select_db('church',$con); // select database
    if(!$sel_db){
        die("Failed to select database". mysql_error());
    }
    // query 
    $query = "Select * from clist"; 
    $result_set = mysql_query($query,$con);
    if(!$result_set){
        die("Failed to Execute Query ". mysql_error());
    }

    while($re = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
     $data[] =$re; // store data in array
    }

    echo json_encode($data); // this will send the array to the ajax call
    mysql_close();
    ?>

   // in XDK


    function onAppReady()
    {
        if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide )
        {
        // Cordova API detected
        navigator.splashscreen.show() ;
        }
     getServer(); 
    }

     // using ajax to communicate with the server
    function getServer(){
        $.get("http://localhost/others/server.php",function(data,status){
             if(status == 'success')
             {
                var result = new Array();
                result = JSON.parse(data); // getting the array from the php
                var i;
              // what your want to do with the data.
             }
        });
    }
```

// this works for me

Comment: Hey, good-looking answer. It might be helpful if you add some additional comments to explain what you are doing at each major step in the code, or add some explanation to the text of your answer.